# Windows 10 upgrade caused my outlook to fail

Tags: microsoft-outlook, windows-10

Upgraded to Windows 10 this morning, all lovely looking, but, now my outlook wont send any mail, can receive emails but when I send I get the following error message:

"Cannot connect to network. Verify your network connection or modem"

I am connected to my wifi, I havnt changed any settings, just did this upgrade.

Comment: Reset Windows Firewall and do a repair of Office

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I googled around a bit and found a solution:

Close Outlook.

Open the Windows **cmd** dialog, as administrator.

Make sure the current folder is **c:\windows\system32** and
enter the following:  **sfc /scannow**

Like this:

[image]

I then did a restart, but that may not be essential.

I could then send email with Outlook (sigh, of relief).

I looked in the log file **cbs.log** and there were pages and pages of warnings and errors. It seems that a lot of files were corrupted during the installation of Windows 10. **Microsoft, hang your heads in shame.**

**VERY IMPORTANT NOTE:**  I'm only telling you what I did. The above procedure changes the system files on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not restarted your PC after the update, you should do it. My Edge browser and the store could not access the Internet directly after updating, after a restart everything worked flawlessly.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the questioner was able to connect to the internet because he wrote that his WiFi was connected and he was able to post the problem. I think it was just a problem with sending emails in Outlook.

Comment: In my case I could connect to the Internet as well. It was only that all Microsoft-related (that is my guess anyway) software was not working internet-wise. It could be because it still installs some things after the first boot, at least that is my guess.